# Let $(X_1 ,Y_1),(X_2 ,Y_2),...,(X_n ,Y_n)$ be a sample from the uniform distribution on a disc $X^2 + Y^2 \leq \theta$, where $\theta$ is unknown.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Let $(X_1 ,Y_1),(X_2 ,Y_2),\ldots,(X_n ,Y_n)$ be a sample from the uniform distribution on a disc $X^2 + Y^2 \leq \theta$, where $\theta$ is unknown. That is, the joint density function of $(X,Y)$ is $f_{(X,Y)}(x,y,\theta)=\frac{1}{\pi \theta^2} \mathbb 1_{ [0,\theta ]} (\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$.

(1) Find a complete sufficient statistic of $\theta$ and its distribution

(2) Find the UMVUE of $\theta$.

What I did is to multiply the density function to find the likelihood function $L=\frac{1}{\pi^n \theta^{2n}} \mathbb 1_{ [0,\theta ]} (\prod_{i=1}^n \sqrt{x^2_i +y^2_i})$, then we know $L=e^{\ln(L)}$, then I find a complete sufficient statistic $T=\sum_{i=1}^n \ln(x^2_i +y^2_i)$; however, I don't know how to find its distribution.

For part (2), I think it's related to the first part. My idea is to see the expectation of $T$ and its relation with $\theta$.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Also when you multiplying those indicators together, you should obtain something other than the $T$ you posted.

Comment: @BGM Just added the edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The likelihood function should be $1/(\pi^n \theta^n)$ when **all** $\sqrt{x_i^2 + y_i^2} \le \theta$, not when their product $\le \theta$.  In particular it depends only on the maximum of $\sqrt{x_i^2 + y_i^2}$.  So that maximum is your
sufficient statistic. To find the distribution of this statistic, calculate the 
probability that all $\sqrt{x_i^2 + y_i^2} \le r$, where $0 \le r \le \theta$.

Comment: Thank you. I think I just understood the question wrong.

Comment: You mean $T=\sqrt{x_{(n)}^2 + y_{(n)}^2}$, where $x_{(n})$ and $y_{(n})$ are order statistic?

Comment: You need to be careful about the notation here. The order is sorted based on the whole term $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, but not sorting individual $x$ and $y$ and put the maximum together. Anyway you should have grasped the key concept and idea here.

Comment: can you transform the joint distribution to polar coordinates and find the marginal $f_{R}(r)$ ? then find the ordered statistic distribution of $r_{(n)}$ ? this would be the distribution correct?